# How do I get dual colour theme for numerals duo watch face?

Tags: color, watchos, beta, themes, apple-watch

I am using the Beta of watchOS 6. In the keynote, I saw the numerals duo watch face with two different colors for each number. Is this exclusive for series 4 or series 5? I am Series 3 user. I did update to the GM version but did not find this color scheme in numerals duo. Attached some screenshots of the Apple website and the keynote.

How do I get such a colour theme for numerals duo watch face?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Source](https://9to5mac.com/2019/06/21/watchos-6-apple-watch-face-support/):

Apple Watch Series 3 running watchOS 6 are limited (at this time) as to the colors used in the Numerals Duo face.  S4 and above can have multiple colors.

S3 watches can also use the Numerals Mono face.  That's just an outline of the numbers with no color fill.

Comment: Just one thing is not correct: Numerals Mono face is also available in filled version on S3. At least in the previous Betas. Didn’t Test on the GM.

Comment: @KevinLieser you are correct, thanks.  Feel free to edit my answer to fix it.